# Automatic folder creation when a Teams user creates a site (warning: rank noob poster)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, modern-document-library

Warning again: This is my first attempt to use SharePoint beyond the web UI. I laid out a folder hierarchy to store per-project files and later got a surprise requirement that any user in the organization has to be able to create a new project, and therefore a new instance, preferably from Teams. I'm trying to salvage the design work and make it usable in a way acceptable to the organization.

I will probably misuse SharePoint terms and reserved words, and welcome corrections. Here's my best attempt to describe the ideal workflow:

1. A user creates a new team in Teams from a template I have created. This much is working - the creation of the team results in a team site in SharePoint, and two channels in the template do create channels in the team, and parallel libraries in SharePoint.
2. We want automatic creation of folders in each of the channel libraries. The names of these folders are consistent and could be hard-coded.

Step two seems out of reach. I appreciate any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to look into pnp provisioning,  as this gives you a lot of ways to customize your Teams,  Groups and SharePoint sites,  including additional  channels,  tabs and folders.

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising, particularly here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning

I'm not entirely certain, though, where the PowerShell needed by PnP can run - it's clear to me that I can run it on a desktop, but is there a place it can be invoked by any user of my SharePoint site?

Comment: Sure, and there are lots of options. I recommend that you take a look at Lauras blog as she has some very good primers: https://laurakokkarinen.com/

Answer (score 0):

As you said, whenever **create a channel** in MS Teams, a corresponding folder is automatically created on **SharePoint Online Documents Library**.

**By design, there is no such option to auto create subfolder under the channel folder.**

I also suggest you to contact **[Microsoft Temas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/ct-p/MicrosoftTeams)** forum regarding this matter and check if you can get additional information on this.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a non-default method, since MS Teams does not allow for folder creation. There are so many possible avenues (PowerApps, PowerAutomate, Flows, Graph, and probably more) that I don't know where to begin to see if there is a possibility of success. I'm certain that if there is I face a massive learning curve to use it.